# Excel formula for a combined straight (non-progressive) and progressive rating table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to create a rating table that combines straight rating and a progressive rating. Here is the example:

---

```
Quantity     Rate   Rate Type

0 - 999      @ 30  Straight Rate
1000 - 1999  @ 25  Straight Rate
2000 - 2999  @ 20  Progressive Rate
3000 - 3999  @ 15  Progressive Rate
4000 - 4999  @ 10  Progressive Rate
5000+        @ 5   Progressive Rate
```

If a table has Straight Rate we can just use vlookup with true match type e.g. quantity 750 @30 = 22500 and quantity 1500 @25 = 37500.

If a table has Progressive Rate then we use the sumproduct formula as described here: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/610095-sumproduct-question-tiered-pricing-grid.html

My question is how can we create an Excel formula take dynamically looks into the Rate Type column and based on whatever is entered in that column, the tier becomes Straight Rate or Progressive Rate.

Example 1:Quantity 750: 750 @30 = 22,500

Example 2:Quantity 2500: 1999 @25 + 501 @20 = 59995

Example 3: Quantity 3250: 1999 @25 + 1000 @20 + 251 @15 = 73740

Thank you for the questions:

The Rate Table is actually dynamic. For example

---

1. Rate decreases

0    - 999   @ 28  Straight Rate (previously @30)
1000 - 1999  @ 20  Straight Rate (previously @25)
2000 - 2999  @ 12  Progressive Rate (previously @20)
and so on.

2. Rate Type becomes Straight instead of Progressive
   0    - 999   @ 28  Straight Rate 
   1000 - 1999  @ 26  Straight Rate 
   2000 - 2999  @ 24  Straight Rate (previously Straight Rate) 
   3000 - 3999  @ 12  Progressive Rate 
   and so on
   Note: once a tier is progressive then all following tiers will also be progressive
3. Different product everything changes 
   0   - 199 @ 100  Straight Rate 
   200 - 299 @ 80   Progressive Rate 
   300 +     @ 75   Progressive Rate

Example of VLOOKUP formula for Straight Rate Table
    A   B   C   D   E   F
1   Quantity    Rate
2
3   0   99  10  Straight 150
4   100 199 9   Straight
5   200 +   8   Straight    =VLOOKUP(E3,A3:C5,3,TRUE)*E3
Cell F will show 1,350

Example of sumproduct formula for Progressive Rate Table
    A   B   C   D   E   F
1   Quantity    Rate
2
3   0   99  10  Progressive 150
4   100 199 9   Progressive 
5   200 +   8   Progressive =SUMPRODUCT(--(e3>=A3:A5),(e3-A3:A5),(C3:C5-C2:C4))
Cell F will show 1,450

Comment: Can you post the formula "as described here", so we don't have to wade through another forum's post and guess what you may have applied? Edit your question to post the formula, then post a comment here to alert your followers.

Comment: Is above table fixed for slabs or you have more slabs in real situation?

Comment: How can 2500 come out to 14995?

Comment: @ZQN Please upload excel file it would easy for us to work.It will give is clear picture of what you want